# Container collaps on addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building my personal portfolio and my `.main-nav` collapses with my `container` when I `.addClass` on `jQuery`. Here is how it looks:

```
.main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  background: #595959;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Jquery:

```
var yourNavigation = $(".main-nav");
    stickyNav = "sticky";
    myHeader = $('.main-header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > myHeader ) {
    yourNavigation.addClass(stickyNav);
  } else {
      yourNavigation.removeClass(stickyNav);
  }
});
```

So when I scroll below the header, as the `.main-nav` becomes fixed, the container under it occupies the space left on top, which makes it collapse.

Any suggestions? Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add some html and move all in a code snippet? That helps a lot when answering your question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your navbar is driven into left corner when it's fixed.

The solution is very simple. Add this to `.sticky` styles:

```
.sticky {
  ...
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  ...
}
```

If it won't work for you, please, post your `html` so we can try it (better, create a JS Fiddle), clarify your question and provide as with a screenshot showing what's wrong.